# Microsoft Translator API in Python

Tags: python, microsoft-translator

I wrote small script in python to translate words from English to Russian language. It uses the [Microsoft-Translator-Python-API](https://github.com/openlabs/Microsoft-Translator-Python-API/) for connection to Microsoft Translator API. However, there is a problem of delay - it takes up to three seconds to call API and get translation.
Does anybody know the way to make it work faster if it's possible?
I'll put piece of my code, just to show what am I doing here:

```
translator   = Translator('My-User-Id',
                            'My-Client-Secret')

current_word = subprocess.check_output(["xsel", "-o"])
translation  = translator.translate(current_word, "ru")
```

Comment: The library uses an http request to get the translation. So your only option to speed it up is to get a faster internet connection.

Comment: The Microsoft server might be intentionally delayed to — for example — discourage use as a service without their advertising content. If so, there would be nothing you could do to speed it up.

Comment: OK, it seems like I didn't make any mistakes in my code, and delay depends only on server-side. Thanks for your answers, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly enough, you can actually do this:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib
args = {
        'client_id': '',#your client id here
        'client_secret': '',#your azure secret here
        'scope': 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
oauth_url = 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13'
oauth_junk = json.loads(requests.post(oauth_url,data=urllib.urlencode(args)).content)
translation_args = {
        'text': "hello",
        'to': 'ru',
        'from': 'en'
        }
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+oauth_junk['access_token']}
translation_url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?'
translation_result = requests.get(translation_url+urllib.urlencode(translation_args),headers=headers)
print translation_result.content
```

and get an immediate response a bunch of times before it slows down (6-7 times with immediate response before it slows down). I haven't used Azure that much so I'm not sure how their rate limiting works, but I'm sure you can pay to up that rate.

(note: I grabbed bits of the above code right out of that microsoft library. just wanted to see what the logic alone behaves like)

Comment: datamarket is now closed and replaced by Azure Portal. This solution does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug.

I have created a python module (its beer-ware :)), to make this process much simpler.

Using it is as simple as:

```
import azure_translate_api

client = azure_translate_api.MicrosoftTranslatorClient('client_id', 'client_secret')
print client.TranslateText('Hello World!', 'en', 'fr')
```

To get more details on where to download this module from and how to use it visit [my github repo](http://goo.gl/hBLUF1).